# Circular button to add items on ListView

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I´m looking to create the classic circular button on a `ListView` to add items. I´ve done that by using `AbsoluteLayout` just fine. But the problem I have is that I cannot make the Button to go with rounded border. No matter what I´ve set it just stays square. For what I´ve read it just seems that Xamarin overrrides the border behaviour. I cannot believe there is not a simple way to solve this.

Can anyone help me out with this?.

EDIT: I´ve tried https://github.com/wilsonvargas/ButtonCirclePlugin but I´m still getting the button with an erratic behaviour:

[image]

```
    <local:CircleButton 
        Text="+" 
        FontSize="Medium" 
        FontAttributes="Bold" 
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.9,0.9,50,50" 
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" 
        HeightRequest="70" 
        WidthRequest="70"/>
```

Comment: https://github.com/wilsonvargas/ButtonCirclePlugin

Comment: @Jason see my edit

Comment: I've create this plugin and It Works fine, check my answer pls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem only in Android 6.0 but it is solved by adding the `BorderRadius` property and assigning it the same value as the height of the button. something like this:

```xml
<local:CircleButton Icon="ic_directions_bike" 
                        FontSize="30" TextColor="Black"
                        HeightRequest="70" WidthRequest="70" 
                        BorderRadius="70" BackgroundColor="#DCDCDC"/>
    <!--This button is not exactly circular-->
    <local:CircleButton FontSize="30" TextColor="Black" 
                        HeightRequest="70" WidthRequest="200" 
                        BorderRadius="20" BackgroundColor="#DCDCDC"/>
```

[image]

This property allows you to create buttons that are not exactly circular, as seen in the image.

Comment: I found that if you disable the hardware acceleration this problem is gone... anyway I tried what you say and it worked. Other question, you reference angular icons like Icon="ic_directions_bike"  what other icons can I use?

Comment: You can find the list of icons [here](https://github.com/wilsonvargas/ButtonCirclePlugin/blob/master/src/ButtonCircle/ButtonCircle.FormsPlugin.Abstractions/Icons.cs) . If this helped you pls mark it as answer.

Comment: Wilson you rock!. Thanks for your answer. If you ever come to Argentina let me know and we have a beer. Saludos compañero.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I can get the background button using Xamarin.Forms. If you are writing Xamarin.Forms you can try.

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Margin="10,10" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" Source="backButton.png">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="btnSetting_Clicked"/>
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
            <Image HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Margin="0,0,10,10" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" Source="settingsButton.png">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="btnSetting_Clicked"/>
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
        </StackLayout>
```